# Is there a name for the game where you can ask a question only after answering one?

Tags: terminology

In Roger Zelazny’s *Blood of Amber*, Merlin and Vinta Bayle are playing the mutual interview game, in which one gains a right to ask an opponent a question by first answering the opponent's question.

Is there a name for this game?

Comment: I believe you can also ask it there: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/

Comment: Fantastic book selection, though I admit a preference for the first five in the series.

Comment: [Riddle-game](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Riddle-game) was an ancient game of the Hobbits, used as a means of settling disputes. The players continued to ask each other riddles until one failed to provide a correct answer.

Comment: @brick Not really. “What is this game called in the book?” would be a topic for [scifi.se]. “What is this game (mentioned in the book) called?” is a topic for [english.se].

Answer (score 3):

Though I am not familiar with any game name, there are phrases for what you are talking about.

**Quid pro quo**, meaning something for something, is a Latin loanphrase that indicates an equal exchange of information, goods, or services.

Other phrases with identical meaning are **tit for tat, like for like, equal exchange, equivalent exchange of information,** and several others which may easily be found by searching a thesaurus for 'quid pro quo'.

Comment: _Quid pro quo, Clarice._

Comment: Well, there are some additional rules in the book, I think, that make the game narrower than just Quid pro quo. AFAIR, no more than one major standing question is allowed, but interviewer can ask for clarifications. If one refuses to answer, the game is over. And so on.